# Azure Webapp - Azure .Net SDK - Setting Site IP Restrictions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, whitelist, azure-sdk-.net

I am attempting to use the Azure .Net SDK in order to retrieve and then manipulate resources within a webapp.

I specifically wish to set Service IP restrictions as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#programmatic-manipulation-of-access-restriction-rules but it has to be manipulated via the SDK.  I understand generic resources may be the best option for this ?

I have the following code in which I can get the website info however I am at a loss at how I determine the resource id of child resources of get a list of the resources

```
            var credentials = new AzureCredentials(servicePrincipal, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            IAzure azure = Azure.Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);


            IWebApp webapp = servicePlan.Manager.WebApps.List().First();
IGenericResource grWebsiteByName = webapp.Manager.ResourceManager.GenericResources.GetById(" "/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/MyFirstAzureWebsite-xxx");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`SiteConfigResourceInner.IpSecurityRestrictions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.models.siteconfigresourceinner.ipsecurityrestrictions?view=azure-dotnet) to set IP security restrictions for webapp. The below code is used to set ip restriction. And you could follow this [article](https://blog.bitscry.com/2019/05/02/getting-azure-web-app-details-from-the-management-api/) to get more details.

```
foreach (var webApp in await azure.WithSubscription(subscription.SubscriptionId).WebApps.ListByResourceGroupAsync(resourceGroup.Name))
{
    SiteConfigResourceInner siteConfigResourceInner = await webSiteManagementClient.WebApps.GetConfigurationAsync(resourceGroup.Name, webApp.Name);
    siteConfigResourceInner.IpSecurityRestrictions.Add(new IpSecurityRestriction("0.0.0.0", "0.0.0.0", "allow"));
    webApp.Inner.SiteConfig = new SiteConfig();

    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in webApp.Inner.SiteConfig.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var value = siteConfigResourceInner.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).GetValue(siteConfigResourceInner, null);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(webApp.Inner.SiteConfig, siteConfigResourceInner.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).GetValue(siteConfigResourceInner));
    }
}
```